# Set selected value of a select that uses Url.Action

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, select

I have the following select:

```
            <select id="companiesDDL" class="compDDL tmpdisplay" onchange="location.href=this.value">
              @foreach (var item in Model.companyList)
              {
                  <option value='@Url.Action("Writeups", "Writeup", new { symbol = item.SecSymbol, status = "A" })'>@item.SecDesc</option>
              }
            </select>
```

This results in a list with options such as

```
<option value='/Writeup/Writeups?symbol=ssl&amp;status=A'>Sasol Limited-Sponsored - ADR</option>
```

I want to set the selected value. I tried

```
$('#companiesDDL  option[value="/Writeup/Writeups?symbol=tsla&;status=A"]').prop("selected", true);
```

but it did not work. How do I do it?

Comment: Try using `attr`: `$('#companiesDDL > option[value="/Writeup/Writeups?symbol=tsla&;status=A"]').attr("selected", "selected");`. If still not working remove `>` in selector.

Comment: If yoru getting `...?symbol=ssl&amp;status=A`, then try `<option value='@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Writeups", "Writeup", new { symbol = item.SecSymbol, status = "A" }))'>` to generate `...?symbol=ssl&status=A`

Comment: But do not use `onchange` to navigate to it. Consider some users will use the keyboard to navigate through the options

Comment: But this would be a lot easier if you just pass a model to the view and bind to your model using the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` method

Comment: Nothing worked. how does using Html.DropdownListFor make it easier?

Comment: @Scott. Just use a view model with properties `string Url` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UrlList` and set the value of `Url` to match the value of one of your options and it will be selected automatically (no javascript required)